# SwiftUI NavigationButton within navigationBarItems

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am looking to be able to use a `NavigationButton` to navigate to a new view within `.navigationBarItems`. This is how I expect it should work:

```swift
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello world")
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        NavigationButton(destination: TestView()) {
            Text("Next")
        }
    )
}
```

However, the "Next" button doesn't do anything! I am aware of PresentationButton which provides a popover view like so:

```swift
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello world")
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            PresentationButton(destination: TestView()) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        )
}
```

But this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Seems like a SwiftUI bug. It's full of bugs, we should wait and see if it fix in the later versions.

Comment: I’m seeing the same thing - I’d be interested to know if there’s something we’re missing, or if it is indeed a confirmed bug.

Comment: I've noticed also that if you call the PresentationButton once, it can't be called again - so could be a bug around BarButtonItems or as Josh said, we could be missing something completely?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As I told you in comments, It was a bug. But it get fixed and it's working now exactly as you expected since **Beta 5**, But remember, `NavigationButton` has changed to `NavigationLink`. So it would be like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello world")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working fine for months and then bam! Stops working. The SwiftUI codebase is one of the most unstable ever released. They need to take it offline and keep it locked up for a while longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a list & you need to navigate through the screens then you should use `NavigationLink` instead of `NavigationButton` cause it's changed recently. For example:-

```
NavigationView{
        
        List(landmarkData) { landmark in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail()){
                
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
            }
                
        }
        
}
```